# Alinhar div dentro de um Box

Tags: css, html5, css3, layout-responsivo, flexbox

Estou usando flexbox, dentro da div pai coloquei uma div com texto, inicialmente está posicionado no topo, quero posicionar essa div no final da div pai. Porém quando coloco position relative; e bottom:0; a div filho permanece no topo da div pai.

Answer (score 1):

Cara se vc está usando `display:flex` no `.pai` vc tem que usar `align-self: flex-end;` no `.filho` Assim ele alinha na base do *container* pai independente do tamanho dele.

Não precisa setar `position` etc... aqui tem um guia do `Flexbox` que pode te ajudar a entender como funcionam os atributos do *flex* https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Veja o exemplo:

```css
.pai {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.filho {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="pai">
  <div class="filho">texto aqui</div>
</div>
```